# "out and out, all in all" are they formal or informal?

Tags: formal-language

Can someone confirm if the below adjectives are formal or informal?

> out and out, all in all

Comment: "all in all" isn't an adjective. Typical usage is "all in all it's been a good year."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would be more common in spoken language rather than written.  Written language tends to use a single (possibly rarer) word where the spoken language uses an idiom or phrase.

However, they are not slang, and would not be out of place in formal speech.

As noted in a comment, "All in all" tends to be adverbal rather than adjectival.

> All in all, this has been a good year, but not the out-and-out great year that we were hoping for last April.